# How to set current working directory in PHP to the script executed directory?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, php-5.3

I have a website on iis7 with php. 
When i call `getcwd()` it returns base directory whith `php-cgi.exe`. But I whant cwd automaticly change to current executed script directory.

How can i configure it via php.ini or iis or else?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to [chdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) in your script:

```
chdir(__DIR__);
```

Or, before PHP 5.3:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Comment: I just don't whant change code. On my old server it was by default.

Answer (score 0):

To the currently executed **script** directory: `chdir(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));`

To the currently executed **file** directory: `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));`

There is a slight difference between them. Script directory is always the directory of the main script file being executed, while the file directory can also be the directory of the included php script file.